# Add Cache as a Raster?

Tags: arcgis-engine

According to step 4 of the MapCruncher sample, 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Multithreaded_MapCruncher/000100000mmm000000/

*Once the cache is finished processing, open Engine or Desktop, navigate to the cache folder, and add the cache as a raster.*

Basically I want to use the precooked maps in a dynamic display environment, but I'm not clear what they mean by "add the cache as a raster".  How can I do this and do you think it would even work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this help doc:  [Map cache usage by clients](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0053000000p9000000.htm)

Specifically:

> **Access the cache as a raster dataset.** To view a cache this way,
>   browse to the directory containing the
>   cache tiles and choose to add the
>   dataset to ArcMap. The cache is
>   represented with the same icon used to
>   add all other rasters using the Add
>   Data button. A cache accessed as a
>   raster is for viewing only and cannot
>   be queried. The advantage with this
>   type of cache is that it is not tied
>   to a map service and can be viewed
>   when disconnected from the server, as
>   long as you can still access the cache
>   directory.